# How you do search all object values inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I search all values inside all objects in an array object in javascript?

```
const array = [
 {
  id: 145,
  name: "Test"
 },
 {
  id: 241,
  name: "Array"
 }
]
```

if I run a function it returns find('a') it returns the second object or if i run find(1) it returns both of the object

Comment: please add the function.

Comment: Check the methods from `Array` and you will find a solution

Comment: What is the expected output? and share your attempt as well.

Comment: You could use find function  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find

Answer (score -3, accepted):

something like this

```
var matches = [];
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    if(array[i].name.indexOf('a') > -1)
    {
        matches.Push(array[i]);
    }
}
return matches;
```

This isn't valid javascript as such, but that is how you would write something like this in javascript.

Comment: I added || for different properties `array[i].name.indexOf('a') || array[i].id.indexOf('a') ` works like a charm thanks

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help.